# Getting Private Users in Tweepy

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I'm using tweepy to follow some people. I try following x's followers, and then y's followers . If there exists a mutual follower , I get the following error

```
[{u'message': u"You've already requested to follow SOMEUSER.", u'code': 160}]
```

So I want to be able to understand whether a user is private or not depending on user's ID , so I can skip trying to follow them in my code. Is this possible ? The API Reference do not have the Object properties.

Answer (score 4):

I know this question was asked a year ago but I came across this question because I was wondering myself. I can now provide an accurate answer for those who come across this page like myself.

```
import tweepy

SCREEN_NAME = 'abcdefg'
CONSUMER_KEY = '1234'
CONSUMER_SECRET = '5678'
ACCESS_TOKEN = '4321'
ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET = '8765'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

u = api.get_user(123456789)
print u.protected
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you keep a local database with the users that you already requested to follow so you don't do unnecessary API calls. You are probably asking to follow the same users over and over again.

If the local database is not an option you can see if a user is private with the [GET users/show API endpoint](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/show) passing a user_id or screen_name. The [response](https://dev.twitter.com/overview/api/users) returns the information you need (check the "protected" field) and much more.

To use this method from tweepy you have the [get_user() method](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#API.get_user).